# vue-template-compiler/package.json missing module with every new project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

Currently, I switched from linux to windows and started to create a programming environment. I don't remember similar problem on linux, but to the point:
**1.** Installed Node.js
**2.** `npm install -g @vue/cli` for CLI install
**3.** `vue create my-app`
**4.** `npm run serve`
Gave:

```
    ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'
Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\base.js:73:32)
at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:225:40)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:225:26)
at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:229:48)
at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\PluginAPI.js:115:25)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 serve: vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Michal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-12-09T203013_264Z-debug.log`
```

**5.** `vue-cli-service inspect --mode production`

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'

Error: Cannot find module 'vue-template-compiler/package.json'
at Function.Module.resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
at Function.Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\nodemodules\@vue\cli-service\lib\config\base.js:73:32)
at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (D:\vueTest\test\nodemodules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:225:40)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Service.resolveChainableWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\nodemodules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:225:26)
at Service.resolveWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\nodemodules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:229:48)
at PluginAPI.resolveWebpackConfig (D:\vueTest\test\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\PluginAPI.js:115:25)`
```

**6.** I tried through `vue ui` but same story, so I installed missing module for created app: `npm install vue-template-compiler`, went smooth, package added.
**7.** `vue run serve`, starting building and then:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 3 errors                  
This dependency was not found:

* vue in ./src/main.js, ./src/App.vue and 1 other

To install it, you can run: npm install --save vue
```

**8.** So i run `npm install --save vue` and then at last `npm run serve` worked:

```
 DONE  Compiled successfully in 2536ms
```

Every single project I created with `vue crate my-app-name` must have had `vue-template-compiler` installed manually, but then I tried with create `vue init webpack-simple my-next-app` everything build up without problems and run.
What is difference with creating new vue project with `create - create a new project powered by vue-cli-service` and `init - generate a project from a remote template (legacy API, requires @vue/cli-init)`

Ps. Yes i tried install `vue-template-compile`r globally.

```
Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Windows 10
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: Not Found
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 5.0.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Edge: 42.17134.1.0
  npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-preset-app:  3.2.0
    @vue/cli-overlay:  3.2.0
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.0
    @vue/cli-plugin-eslint: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.1
    @vue/cli-service: ^3.2.0 => 3.2.0
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  3.2.0
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  2.3.0
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.0
    @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0
    babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  2.0.3
    babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  4.0.1
    eslint-plugin-vue: ^5.0.0-0 => 4.7.1
    vue-eslint-parser:  2.0.3
    vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.1
    vue-loader:  15.4.2
    vue-style-loader:  4.1.2
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.6.0
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: Not Found
```

Why vue does not see @vue/cli in new project? That was first thing I installed :/

Answer (score 2):

recently I have faced the same issue, I did fix using an update few packages my current version as per below.

1. "vue":"2.5.17"
2. "vue-template-compiler": "2.5.17"

Comment: It's weird, because I installed everything fresh and latest versions. I have not spotted anything useful during looking in GH project's repository.

Comment: It's weird, because I installed everything fresh and latest versions. I have not spotted anything useful during looking in GH project's repository.

I did upgrade as you wrote, and installed vue-custom-element. But problem still exist. So for now I stand with my solution, I only have 3-4 projects in vue so few commands dont make difference for me now. I will try fix it in free time.

Comment: i created new project, and before run in app catalog i typed npm install:


npm WARN @vue/cli-service@3.2.0 requires a peer of vue-template-compiler@^2.0.0 but none was installed.

up to date in 3.434s

So question is why during install vue cli - vue-template-compiler is not installed?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2109#issuecomment-411384824) you need to install `vue-template-compiler` manually, running `npm i -g vue-template-compiler` fixes the problem.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer if one is not using `vue-template-compiler` directly in their project.

Comment: Tests should run in pipelines as well, installing global libraries is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update vue-template-compiler to the exact same version as vue was.
In my case both were version 2.6.14

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have faced the same issue, I did a fix using an update few packages my current version as per below.

"vue":"2.5.22"
"vue-template-compiler": "2.5.22

I posted also in Vue.js forum
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/installation-nightmare/54705

It is very hard for a new user to figure out how and where to do the fixes

What helped me was https://itnext.io/vuejs-and-webpack-4-from-scratch-part-1-94c9c28a534a and https://itnext.io/getting-started-vue-js-and-visual-studio-code-6990f92e918a

Answer (score 0):

I am running Vue 2 and got this error seemingly out of nowhere. The solutions for Vue 3 did not work for me. What worked was rolling back to an old version of package.json. I had run `npm fix` and updated packages were introduced which caused this error. Reverting those solved the issue.

1. delete `package-lock.json`
2. change `package.json` to a version that worked
3. run `npm install`