# How to solve 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I am getting an error when trying to run `npm run serve`. At first I installed node.js then vue as well as vue/cli.
But when I am trying to run server as -> npm run serve at that time I'm getting error like 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I used below codes for installation:

```
npm install -g vue
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

[image]

can someone guide me what to do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try running `npm install` before `npm run serve`.

Comment: npm install -g @vue/cli-service

Comment: @DanieleTesta: This was the only thing that worked for me. Maybe post as an answer?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

I think you are using `cmd` in windows.

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder and after that run `npm i` from the cmd.

Then try running `npm run serve` again and see if it works this time

Comment: @Sakib without deleting node_modules, it worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Done all step and when cmd using npm run serve then get error 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! smb-inseego@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the smb-inseego@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-27T16_32_39_297Z-debug.log

Comment: Try to install `vue-cli-service`

run 

`npm install -g @vue/cli`

then run `npm run serve`

Comment: Worked for me too, in my case when I incorrectly switched between two branches (git) and left some changes, that problem occurred.

Comment: worked for me because i did npm needed to reinstall because it was installed on another platform.

Comment: this was perfect for my issue, switching between a non vue and back to a vue branch.

Answer (score 61):

### Install vue/cli-service globally

```
npm install @vue/cli-service -g
```

This will install [global npm package](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-packages-globally).

`@vue/cli-service` is usully installed as global, because you do not usually copy these types of packages to every project.

If the global npm package gets corrupted, it is not stored in `node_modules` folder, but rather in other depending on the os. Therefore removing node_modules does not help. Locations for global node_modules folders are

- `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` (Win10) or
- `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` (Linux),

check [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages) on how to locate global packages.

Comment: For me, personally, this is the only answer that helped

Comment: Same here..  together with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53712893/vue-template-compiler-package-json-missing-module-with-every-new-project/53718006

Answer (score 17):

it will depend on the package manager you are using

1. delete **node_modules**
2. if you are using **yarn** run `yarn` or `yarn install` and then `yarn serve`
3. if you are using **npm** run `npm install` and then `npm run serve`

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the package `@vue/cli-service` is installed in my local node_modules environment, but not my global environment, so it cannot be used as a command. I type `.\node_modules\.bin\vue-cli-service serve` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

As it is mentioned in terminal that node_modules is missing from your project, so you can't directly use **npm run serve**, first you have to do **npm install** then do **npm run serve**. It will work fine

Comment: This solved a similar problem I was having with building an ESP32 project, restful_server.  npm install, then npm run build and the project would compile after the dist folder showed up.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I ran below commands in GitBash and it worked fine

1. `npm install`
2. `npm run serve`

Answer (score 2):

1. If you are using cmd in windows.
2. deleting the node_modules folder and after that run npm istall from
   the cmd.
3. run npm run serve and see if it works this time

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have checked the folder of node_modules was missing. I am using Windows. So I run this in cmd.

1. npm install
2. npm run serve

Then I check it in localhost like usual.

Answer (score 1):

This issue mostly happens when either @vue/cli is not installed or in most cases,

> @vue/cli is already installed and you are currently working on a project and when running

- `yarn serve` or `npm run serve`.

Most at times, this issue is been caused by broken dependencies.
to fix this issue, simple run

- `yarn install` or `npm install`

depending on your package manager.

Answer (score 1):

well after trying all the solutions above and it still haven't worked for you then you probably have a stupid space in the full directory of your Vue project like in my case. so remove that that space and it will work from then on.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to set the NODE_ENV=development and run npm install again

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the project path to one without spaces, it worked on windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem in windows. Then
first I deleted the node_module. then I run `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you should modify **package.json** to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service.cmd serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service.cmd build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service.cmd lint"
  }
```

,

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using windows + WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04). Looking at the logs generated after trying to run `npm i` I noticed that my WSL2 environment d**id not have python2 installed**. So to solve I ran the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-get install python2`
2. `rm -rf node_modules`
3. `npm i`
4. `npm run serve`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same in Windows. Had to run npm install again. Then it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, what's the difference between @vue/cli and @vue/cli-service? When you install both, they show different number of packages installed. The latter solved my issue actually but everyone keeps saying install @vue/cli.

Answer (score 0):

try running `npm i` or `npm install` and then proceed to run `npm i vue` after previous installation done. works for me

Answer (score 0):

you need use "npm install" at Command Line

Answer (score 0):

Before running "npm install", try running this command first:

```
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I got the error below when I ran `npm run serve` from the CMD command line,

> 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.

I got past this familiar error by using the following command to add the npm folder to the PATH that CMD searches for executables:

```
path=%path%;C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

where `<USERNAME>` is your Windows user profile directory name. Only then was I able to run the following commands successfully:

```
npm install 
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue for me was renaming the directory. I had used the symbol "&" on the folder name and it seems to break things, so changing it to "and" fixed the issue.

This will probably be an incredibly niche thing, but if I help even 1 person it's fine by me.

Answer (score -1):

I have a project, I can run it well on Linux, but i have the same issue on windows, I solve it this way (I hope in your case it works too):

1. Delete the node_modules
2. Install it again with `npm i`

Comment: This has already been mentioned in some of the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*