# Encounter " 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command" after using npm install --production

Tags: node.js, npm-install, vue-cli

Our production environment have to using "npm install --production" to install the project, but when trigger "npm run serve" that encounter Below error:

'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

Here is the command sequence :

1. npm install --production
2. npm run serve

Below is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",`enter code here`
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

Could anyone help on this case ? Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Does the `serve` script require your devDependencies?  If you run `npm install` then `npm run serve` does it work?

Can you run `vue --version` from your prod environment?  That error makes me think the whole `@vue/cli` global install is missing.

Post may be a dupe: [How to solve 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58579843/how-to-solve-vue-cli-service-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm)

Just in case, you may want to `rm -rf node_modules` then install, then serve.

Comment: I run npm install then npm run serve it will work. But using "'npm install --production'' even in my local.In Visual studio code run vue --version show this :
PS D:\xx\app> vue --version
vue : File C:\Users\jinjo2\AppData\Roaming\npm\vue.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ vue --version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: "With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies." Sounds like this is working as intended then.  I think the expected deploy to production is to make a distribution of javascript + html files.  Then those are served up by a webserver, not "npm run serve".  If you intend to use the "serve" script it relies on devDependencies in your `package.json`, thus it won't work if you use the --production flag.  That's my guess.

Comment: Yes, when using --production flag it won't build with devDependencies, but even I add    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0" into dependencies but still cannot success to run 'npm run serve' and throw 'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command error message.